# VLMC package in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to analyze a literary text using the VLMC package in R. When trying to fit the data into the markov chain, i get this error:

> Error in vlmc(txt, cutoff = 5) :    alphabet too large; currently
>   limited to maximally 255 letters

Is there any way to bypass this limit?  What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Don't you think this is a "contact the maintainer" sort of question???